# Workflow automation in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Could anyone please advice me in how i can use workflows in node js project. I never used work flows like approval / rejection. sending email on particular deadline. I don't know the approach to begin with.

My requirement is to send an approval / rejection email on 2nd day. if supervisor did not respond then again send the email on the 5th day to supervisor. After 5th day it will be auto approved.

there are others workflows as well. I think once i got the idea, i will make it work. Really appreciate if someone can guide me it.

Do we have to maintain data in staging table or maintain flags in columns?

Regards
Meet

Answer (score 0):

You can use `node-cron` for scheduling and `nodemailer` for email trasporting. For an example:

```
 let cron = require('node-cron');
 let nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

 // e-mail message options
 let mailOptions = {
    from: '<FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS>',
    to: '<TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS>',
    subject: 'Email from Node-App: A Test Message!',
    text: 'Some content to send'
 };

 // e-mail transport configuration
 let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: '<FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS>',
      pass: '<FROM_EMAIL_PASSWORD>'
    }
});

cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
// Send e-mail
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
  });
});
```